# Disable selecting certain items in listbox?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have an multiselect listbox that i need to disable users from selecting certain items in the listbox. I've tried looking at the listbox enable but that seems to be for the whole listbox only. Any ideas? Here's my listbox, i currently is looping through the item hoping to disable the item:

```
Dim lItem As Long
For lItem = 0 To Sheet1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Sheet1.ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        Sheet1.ListBox1.Enabled(lItem) = False ' don't work?
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Limited info, but can't you have 2 separate list box's, and only enabled one for your users?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think you can 'disable' a set of rows on a listbox. You could however, perhaps, each time a row is selected, check if it meets your disabled criteria and if so, un-select it?

Comment: I only want 1 where only certain rows can be selected but not others.

Comment: Is the listbox multi-select?

Comment: @CLR yes it's mutli select.

Comment: Only way I can see you doing this is with an event, using a mask to prevent changes to rows that you've marked (elsewhere) as disabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
For it = 0 To Sheet1.ListBox1.ListIndex 

  If Sheet1.ListBox1.Selected(it) Then
     Sheet1.ListBox1.Selected(it) = False 
     Sheet1.ListBox1.RemoveItem (it)   
  End If

Next
```

Line1 : goes through all the indexes of the listbox

Line2 : find the selected item

Line3 : deselects

Line4 : removes the item selected

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**  This takes the user's selection and effectively remove it, while retaining the original ListIndex for all items.

```
Listbox1.List(MyListbox1.ListIndex) = " "
```

Then you can use code to check for a value of " "

**Option 2:**  Move `Listbox1.List(Listbox1.ListIndex)` from one column (visible) to another that is not (width = 0).  This would also retain the original listindex order and the value if you need to reinstate it (make it a valid option).

**Option 3:** To get the illusion of grayed out rows, as long as there are no scroll bars, you could place borderless labels with a gray background over the listbox.  The .top value would need to be calculated using the listbox's .top plus X * ListIndex to place it directly over the non-available option.  Then make the label's caption = to the listbox selection.  (I never said it was easy, just that it was possible)