# Creating a sequential number series using a userform for a database

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have userform that I created in order to feed a droplist/combobox that will contain IP addresses.  This excel database is being used to deploy computers and equipment throughout new facilities as they open  As you can see in the userform I have two options...One radio Button that allows you to input one IP address while the other one allows you to enter a starting IP address and an ending IP address to create a range.  The input boxes only appear when the corresponding option is TRUE.  The single IP input box writes perfectly into the correct column, but when I click the radio button to add a range, enter the starting and ending of the range and click SUBMIT nothing gets entered.  The cursor just goes down one cell from the first blank cell in the column.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Submit_Data_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arrays")
Dim N As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim X, Y, A, B

N = sh.Range("I" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Me.Add_single_IP.Value = True Then
    sh.Range("I" & N + 1).Value = Me.sgle_IP_add_tb1
    Else
If Me.Add_IP_Rng.Value = True Then

    A = Me.rge_IP_start_tb2.Value
    B = Me.Rge_IP_End_tb2.Value

    For N = I2 To I

    ActiveCell.Value = X
    ActiveCell.Offset(X + 1, Y).Select
    Next N
    X = 0
    Y = 0
    End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I am adding a CLEAR command at the end of the code after the data is submitted and also a MsgBox to indicate that the data has been added.

Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add Option Explicit to the top of your code and the compiler will tell you that !2 and I are undefined. You could simplify the form by removing the option buttons and having only 2 text boxes. If the user leaves the end address blank set it to the start address so that only 1 address is added. You should also add some validation of the user input. For example.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Submit_Data_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rngTarget As Range
    Dim s1 As String, ip1 As Variant
    Dim s2 As String, ip2 As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Arrays")
    Set rngTarget = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    If Me.Add_single_IP = True Then
        s1 = Me.sgle_IP_add_tb1
        s2 = s1
    Else
        s1 = Me.rge_IP_start_tb2
        s2 = Me.rge_IP_End_tb2
    End If

    ' split string into bytes
    ip1 = Split(s1, ".")
    ip2 = Split(s2, ".")

    ' validate
    Dim msg As String
    If UBound(ip1) <> 3 Or UBound(ip2) <> 3 Then
        msg = "IP must be n.n.n.n"
    ElseIf ip1(3) > 255 Or ip2(3) > 255 Then
        msg = "Host must be 1 to 255"
    ElseIf ip1(3) > ip2(3) Then
        msg = s1 & " is greater then " & s2
    ElseIf ip1(0) <> ip2(0) Or ip1(1) <> ip2(1) Or ip1(2) <> ip2(2) Then
        msg = "Different networks"
    End If

    ' failed validation
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical, s1 & "-" & s2
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' calc range and write to sheet
    n = ip2(3) - ip1(3) + 1
    For i = 1 To n
       Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0) ' move down
       rngTarget = Join(ip1, ".")
       ip1(3) = ip1(3) + 1
    Next
    MsgBox n & " addresses added ", vbInformation, s1 & "-" & s2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help it is exactly what I need and streamlines everything.  I added the code with the Option Explicit but I get a 424 error...

Comment: @DBrown Can you single step the program with F8 and identify the line

Comment: @DBrown You must have a variable somewhere that is undefined. Option Explicit ensures all your variables have a Dim. It catches spelling mistakes and other errors that might otherwise go unnoticed. It can seem like a pain at first but it saves time in the long run.

Comment: but when I add the Option Explicit it errors out... when I add it to the top it adds it at the bottom of the preceding SUB ...so where do I add the Option Explicit??

Comment: @dbrown Outside the sub at the very top of the edit screen. Or you can use Tools->Options->Require Variable Declarations and it gets added automatically to your code.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  Is there a way that I can gray out or make the IP adresses in the list box NOT visible after they are used in the table that they are feeding?  I just don't want to re-select the address after I have already assigned it to the CC machine.  I assume data validation but I don't know how in VBA.

Comment: @dbrown I don't know that much above forms but a quick search found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003702/.